# Using firebase auth with facebook

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

When trying to login to my web app during testing on my android phone, I get this message:

"firebase.js:75 Uncaught Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https.."

I added my firebase url to Valid OAuth redirect URIs on my fb app - https://.firebaseio.com/ I added my app id and name to firebase in auth section. Am i missing something? thanks

I'm using chrome remote debugging here: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/app/people

Could this be why it's putting up a fuss?

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

console.log(provider);
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
 // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access theFacebook API.
   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
// The signed-in user info.
  var user = result.user;
  console.log(user, token);
  UserService.setUser(user, token);
// ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // The email of the user's account used.
  var email = error.email;
  // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
  var credential = error.credential;
  console.log(errorCode);

  });
```

Comment: Authentication will not work when you load a file with `file://`. You'll need to load the HTML from a proper web server to make it work.

Comment: Yeah. I thought so. Im using phonegaps lightweight adb to run the app on my phone. Perhaps, i can run it off node somehow. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: just start a local server. there are many node modules for that, just search on npm.

Comment: I am using Ionic 2 framework and getting the same issue in Android! In browser, it works fine.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll do that. Did you have to change deviceReady to documentReady? to get it to run in your browser?

Comment: It seems to be working (i.e., it's redirecting correctly) but now I'm getting an internal server error when it calls getRedirectResult. I'm using this in oAuth redirect in fb: https://my-app-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

Answer (score 3):

Found a work-around in regards to Facebook login which works on Ionic 1 and should in principal also work on Ionic 2.

Add the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4
In the auth code, I've added the following:

```
if ((window.cordova && device.platform == 'iOS') || (window.cordova && device.platform == 'Android')) {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile'], function(result) {
        provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.authResponse.accessToken);
        Auth.$signInWithCredential(provider).then(function(authData) {
            // User successfully logged in
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Login error
        });
    }, function(error) {
        // Login error
    });
} else {
    provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    Auth.$signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(authData) {
        // User successfully logged in
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Login error
    });
}
```

Basically, this will make sure that on device it uses the Facebook login SDK while it will use Firebase signInWithPopup when running in a browser

Answer (score 1):

The following operations: signInWithPopup, signInWithRedirect, linkWithPopup, linkWithRedirect and getRedirectResult are only supported from an http/https environment. You can use the remaining apis from a file environment.